# LinkedIn v2 API: Upload an image without curl

Tags: node.js, curl, linkedin-api

The LinkedIn docs for uploading an image have a step for uploading an image using curl:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares

I am using a node HTTP client and don't have curl installed on my web servers. How would I go about formatting an HTTP request the way that `curl --upload-image` formats an http request?

I understand that `curl --upload-image` is a PUT request, but what headers do I need to send? How should the body of the request be formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to get a PUT for imageUpload working after a bunch of trial & error. I needed the following headers:

```
'Authorization': `Bearer ${ access_token }`,
'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
'Content-Type': 'image/png'
```

And the body is simply the image file contents.

Comment: would you care sharing your js? particularly interested in initial setup, getting the access token

Comment: Also would love to see how you did this.

Comment: SEARCH ON YOUTUBE LINKEDIN OAUTH2 by API ACEDMY